# RabbitMQ Consumer : AlreadyClosedException

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, consumer

I have a simple RabbitMQ publisher and consumer code listed below.

First, I created 10 count of different message in My_Tasks queue. When I try to get these message, one by one and with autoAck flag as false, I can read the first message, but acknowledge could not be sent to the RabbitMQ server. I get an error written below;

Publisher;

```
var qName = "My_Tasks";
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare(qName, durable: true, false, false, null);

        var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

        var prop = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
        prop.Persistent = true;

        channel.BasicPublish("", routingKey: qName, prop, body);
    }
}
```

Consumer;

```
var qName = "My_Tasks";
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare(qName, durable: true, false, false, null);
        channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        channel.BasicConsume(qName, autoAck: false, consumer);

        consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
        {
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body.ToArray());
            channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
        };
    }
}
```

**RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.AlreadyClosedException: 'Already closed: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Application, code=200, text='Goodbye', classId=0, methodId=0'**

at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SessionBase.Transmit(Command cmd)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.ModelSend(MethodBase method, ContentHeaderBase header, ReadOnlyMemory 1 body)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Model.BasicAck(UInt64 deliveryTag, Boolean multiple)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.RecoveryAwareModel.BasicAck(UInt64 deliveryTag, Boolean multiple)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.AutorecoveringModel.BasicAck(UInt64 deliveryTag, Boolean multiple)
   at QueueExample.Consumer.Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0(Object model, BasicDeliverEventArgs ea) in D:\Projects\RabbitMQTutorial\QueueExample\QueueExample.Consumer\Program.cs:line 36
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Events.EventingBasicConsumer.HandleBasicDeliver(String consumerTag, UInt64 deliveryTag, Boolean redelivered, String exchange, String routingKey, IBasicProperties properties, ReadOnlyMemory`1 body)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ConcurrentConsumerDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__0()

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer of the error. My example application is an consoleApp so while consumer receive the message the connection was already closed. When a write a Connsole.ReadLine() for waiting response for closing the connection, all the message could read by the consumer.

That is the temporary solution, you can find your own solution from this perspective.

```
var qName = "My_Tasks";
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare(qName, durable: true, false, false, null);
        channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        channel.BasicConsume(qName, autoAck: false, consumer);

        consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
        {
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body.ToArray());
            channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
        };

        //Solution is here
        Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key to Continue..");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*This should be a comment, but I am missing reputation.*

Was your solution already working? Where do you define your connection to the broker? Are you using the broker in a docker-compose configuration? In this case, your broker must connect to

```
rabbitmq://host.docker.internal
```

*When I started working with RabbitMQ in .Net Core I experienced the same issues.
As my application (microservice pattern) was in an early stage I switched to [MassTransit framework](http://masstransit-project.com/) which handles everything. I can highly recommend it, since it "just works" and you can fully focus on your desired system functionality.*